# install RMySQL for Mac

Tags: r, rmysql

I get below error when I try to  install Mysql package (MAC OS)

```
install.packages('RMySQL')

  package ‘RMySQL’ is available as a source package but not as a binary

Warning in install.packages :
 package ‘RMySQL’ is not available (for R version 3.1.0)
```

I am not sure what I need to set in order for this to work.

Comment: As you were told by the error message, there is no binary for Mac (well, for Mavericks, which is presumably what you're on). So you'll have to build it from source. Your first step should probably be to download the source, read the INSTALL instructions, maybe do some Googling and then give it try.

Comment: website says source not available for OS - Mavericks

Comment: No, the source is _always_ [available](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RMySQL/index.html).

Comment: Yes .. Got the source and installed. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The author of RMySQL [no longer provide binary packages](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/Main/RMySQL), so you will have to build from source.

I have posted the complete solution in another thread: [Installing RMySQL in mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24537257/installing-rmysql-in-mavericks).

Basically, in order for `install.packages('RMySQL', type='source')` to work correctly, what you are lacking are:

1. Make sure you have "gcc" available.
2. Install MySQL client somewhere, e.g., via Homebrew.
3. Configure and build RMySQL from source in RStudio or in Terminal:

   - Set the 2 environment variables **PKG_CPPFLAGS** and **PKG_LIBS** to indicate where the *include* and *lib* are.
   - Run `install.packages('RMySQL', type='source')` in RStudio or `R CMD INSTALL RMySQL_x.x-x.tar.gz` in Terminal

Comment: At the moment anyway, it appears that binaries are available on CRAN for all the standard R variants: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RMySQL/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Installing from source worked well for me. For those who are new to R, the way to install from source is:

```
install.packages('RMySQL', type='source')
```