# package ‘RMySQL’ is available as a source package but not as a binary

Tags: r, macos, installation

I am receiving the above error when I try to install this package. Reading this question [install RMySQL for Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23784919/install-rmysql-for-mac) I read the install guide.

Here's what is said:

```
During installation, RMySQL looks for the MySQL headers and libraries
in the system directories.  If these are not installed in system-wide
directories (or if you want to use an alternate MySQL distribution),
you may specify which MySQL directory(ies) to use through one of the
following:

   1. The shell variables PKG_CPPFLAGS and PKG_LIBS (using Bourne shell)

       export PKG_CPPFLAGS="-I<include-dir>"
       export PKG_LIBS="-L<library-dir> -lmysqlclient"

       For instance, on some 64 systems (e.g., Linux) you may need to set

       export PKG_CPPFALGS="-I/usr/include/mysql"
       export PKG_LIBS="-L/usr/lib64/mysql -lmysqlclient"
```

I have browsed my computer, I don't believe that those directories exist.

I have installed XAMPP previously on my Mac and wondered if the directories needed are in there somewhere since XAMPP uses MySQL?

Can I just download the directories somewhere?
How can I find if they are already on my computer?

```
export PKG_CPPFALGS="-I/usr/include/mysql"
export PKG_LIBS="-L/usr/lib64/mysql -lmysqlclient"
```

I'm at a loss for what to do next?

Comment: Read the INSTALL file that comes with RMySQL.

Comment: I did. I even quoted it in the question. The install file tells me to run the export commands above but the directories quoted do not appear to exist

Comment: What it actually says is "for instance" ...

Comment: Right. Which is why I tried looking around in XAMPP since MySQL was installed via XAMPP. The the root folders do not appear to exist or I cannot find them

Comment: For instance means you have to adapt the instructions to your distribution and MySQL version. It also may be that XAMPP is not sufficiently complete for use with RMySQL.  Safest would be to get MySQL directly from the MySQL site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind installing another MySQL server via Homebrew, I have posted the complete solution in another thread: [Installing RMySQL in mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24537257/installing-rmysql-in-mavericks)

---

But in your case, I do find those directories in XAMPP that contain the same necessary MySQL header and library files as those installed via Homebrew.

So you can set the environment variables and build in the Terminal way:

```
% export PKG_CPPFALGS="-I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include"
% export PKG_LIBS="-L/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib -lmysqlclient"
## RMySQL_x.x-x.tar is the source package you have manually downloaded
% R CMD INSTALL RMySQL_x.x-x.tar
```

or in the RStudio way:

```
> Sys.setenv(PKG_CPPFLAGS = "-I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include")
> Sys.setenv(PKG_LIBS = "-L/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib -lmysqlclient")
## It will automatically download the source package in the remote repo
> install.packages("RMySQL", type = "source")
```